# Convert double to string in a clr-property using attributes

Tags: c#, wpf

Im looking for a method of specifying how a double-property should be converted to a string in the view (mainly number of decimals) without having to make the property a string-property and without having to add a converter in the binding.

```
double _value = 1.234234234234234;
[TypeConverter(typeof(DoubleToStringConverter))]
public double Value
{
  get { return _value; }
  set { _value = value; }
}
```

Ive tried a TypeConverter (as above) without result... Any suggestions?

Comment: How bad do you need that exact functionality?  It seems too much trouble.  I'd just add a ValueString property and call it solved.

Answer (score 1):

What about specifying the string format in the binding like this?

```
<TextBox Binding="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0.###}}" />
```

Value should get automatically converted to a string with the specified format for display on the view.

Comment: My goal was to not use conversion/formatting in the binding but close to the property in my presentationmodel instead.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you are going for by doing the string formatting solely in the viewmodel. I haven't seen any other way other than to provide a string property in your viewmodel if you prefer not to use converters in the binding. In some special cases I've worked with, I provided two properties in the viewmodel, a numeric one and a string one, that both refer back to the same numeric field to allow the view to bind to either one.